# What are merits of having a PhD degree?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, career-path

What are the benefits of having a PhD degree? Why are PhD programs so competitive? I mean, why do many people apply for PhD programs?

In STEM fields, it is usually possible to get a better-paid job in industry with a bachelor's or master's degree. On the other hand, PhD programs are usually long, hard and low-paying — if there is any paying at all — and job prospects for PhD graduates are not that impressive too. So, what am I missing? Why do so many talented people try to get into PhD programs if they can get better jobs outside academia? Is it merely because of personal interest in research, teaching or learning?

Although opinions are important, I sincerely appreciate it if facts and experiences are shared. I agree that this question can be opinion-based but one of the reasons why I am asking this is that choosing to do a PhD degree and possibly pursuing an academic career is a very important decision. Based on personal experience, I have seen many fresh graduates who face the same question (and also a few people that, first, made a decision then faced the question, only to realize that it is late) and I hope that, apart from satiating my personal curiosity, it will provide factual and helpful information for those who have not made their minds yet.

Comment: Apart from personal curiosity, I am asking this question mostly because I like to have a better understanding of academic environment, from which I have been away for some time.

Comment: "better jobs outside academia" - *better* in what respect? Paid better? Most likely. But better in terms of freedom in choice of tasks, flexibility in working style, ownership of what you work on, autonomy in collaboration with internal and external partners, authority to draw further people in to your tasks, etc.? Probably not so much.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you have nice points. As you guessed, by better, I meant better paid. I'll update the question to reflect it.

Comment: As your question now assumes more openly that the decision is only about payment, I have put my doubts about that already uttered in my comment into an [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/93561/14017).

Comment: Because _is not all about money_ and _better payed jobs_ do not make _better jobs_.

Comment: This question should be closed. It is too broad to be answered. Rather, it does create conflicting views and opinions. Many things are unclear in the question as well. The PhD status depends on country, field, and various other parameters.

Comment: @Coder I object. Yes, there is a dependency, and exactly this is the reason to keep the question open and generate discussion.

Comment: @LeonMeier Why not then move this to chat to have more efficient and timely discussion?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson That  is exactly what I am hoping for: research-based facts. However, personal experiences are also important and I am glad that people have shared their experiences.

Comment: Some people truly like the act of doing research and advancing knowledge. Even for industry, a PhD is becoming a requirement to do R&D.

Comment: In my case, I chose a PhD over a masters because in the MS program I'd have to pay tuition. In the PhD program I am given a stipend, and also, you earn a MS halfway through anyway. I could just quit after getting that, if I want.

Comment: If you dream of doing research, and contributing to civilization's scientific knowledge like your heroes did, then what are you going to do other than a PhD?  There are almost no jobs that let you do pure research without a PhD.

Comment: In my own (STEM) PhD program, there were at least two people who had had lucrative careers in industry, accumulated enough to be financially independent, and were basically doing the PhD to keep their minds active.

Comment: @Coder: Because chat is not a way to have efficient discussions?

Comment: @iammax: Choosing a PhD over a masters is not possible in many places. Masters is a prerequisite for even being considered for starting a PhD.

Comment: This question can be reworded to require a less opinion based answer. It is a useful question and I'm upvoting it.

Comment: There are as many answers as personal preferences and it also strongly depends on which country and institution you are talking about. Examples I know personally: (1) for the joy of researching and learning, (2) because it's a requirement to become a professor, (3) because it leads to an aristocratic status in society and better paid jobs (in German-speaking countries, for example), (4) because the University provides a safe space to do your own stuff at your own pace outside the job market, (5) because you were persuaded by a professor to join his team during your undergraduate years...

Comment: And regarding payment, again, it depends on the country. In German-speaking countries in particular, salaries are regulated and you can earn more by doing the same by just having a PhD. Furthermore, in most cases first-year postdocs are paid better than a just-graduated in industry, and a PhD very often leads to better jobs later. Which, in my opinion is the wrong reason to pursue a PhD and explains why there are so many doctors in German-speaking countries (many people pursuing the financial and status incentives), many of them having nothing to do with research or academia.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I should note that this answer is going to focus on the research-based Doctor of Philosophy (PhD) degree and [ScD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Science) equivalent This answer does not apply similar degrees in other fields (e.g., [EdD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Education), [DBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Business_Administration), [DrPH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Public_Health), etc.) since the motivation for those is much more field dependent.

First, lets start with the obvious, you get a PhD because you want to teach at the college level. Barring the [Professor of Practice](https://www.engineering.cornell.edu/research/faculty/FacultyDevelopment/profesor-of-practice-guidelines.cfm) which requires significant industry experience, the PhD is the minimum requirement to get a tenure-track position. There used to be some fields such as nursing that were the exception to this, but they are now [converging on PhD requirements](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/46281588/j.nedt.2010.07.00220160606-394-1j9i2oz.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1500825693&Signature=KAlzNhq7fRHC2x3GlbqQVOWGYg8%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DIf_you_havent_got_a_PhD_youre_not_going.pdf). Despite the [general oversupply of PhDs](https://www.nature.com/news/2011/110420/full/472276a.html) as well, some fields are [actually facing shortfalls](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.3200/JOEB.80.1.47-51).

Another reason to purse a PhD is because you are hoping to purse a career where it is advantages to have one. [Consulting](http://www.sciencemag.org/careers/2014/09/science-careers-guide-consulting-careers-phd-scientists) is a good example of this, most [Chief Science Officers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Scientific_Officer) also hold a PhD as well. There is [increasingly](http://registan.net/2012/11/26/the-dc-game-and-paula-broadwell/) a [perception](http://foreignpolicy.com/2012/11/29/so-you-want-to-get-a-ph-d-to-get-ahead-in-dc/) that PhD is required to work in policy in Washington, D.C. Furthermore, despite the ongoing perception that a PhD isn't valued by industry, [private-sector R&D labs](http://www.sciencemag.org/careers/2009/05/academia-or-industry-finding-right-fit) are [staffed by PhDs](https://www.nsf.gov/statistics/infbrief/nsf14310/) and industry investment [in R&D is growing](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2013/08/08/the-private-sector-is-spending-more-on-rd-than-ever/?utm_term=.9d17a74b3094).

Of course, these lead to a very salient argument against getting a PhD due to the time investment [leading to monetary loss in the long term](http://www.economist.com/node/17723223). Generally this is irrelevant if someone is dead set on a job in academia, you have to get the "[union card](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dec/essay.phd.html)." There is more risk involved if you are planning on going into industry since in theory a Masters should be enough. This does lead to some PhD applicants who [intend on dropping out](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskAcademia/comments/2pbbx1/apply_for_a_phd_but_when_you_get_the_masters_drop/) once they get their Masters. These are generally rare though. Thus, some, likely most, people get a PhD because they want a career in *X* and the PhD will make them competitive for that career.

There is a common perception that people do a PhD because it is "next." Although [a survey of UK students](https://www.vitae.ac.uk/news/new-what-do-researchers-want-to-do-report-now-available) indirectly supports this for applicants without an employment history, it does not for those with one. Generally the most common theme seems to be "intellectual curiosity and interest," even more so [among older applicants](https://chrisblattman.com/2013/06/12/when-are-you-too-old-for-a-phd/). In fact, I would argue that the admissions committee should filter out people that are just doing it because it is "next." PhD programs are not easy and have [attrition rates that exceed 50%](http://www.chronicle.com/article/PhD-Attrition-How-Much-Is/140045). Things may not be easy for those that leave (e.g., [one](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/features/the-phd-experience-this-far-and-no-further/2015113.article#survey-answer), [two](https://chroniclevitae.com/news/445-in-hindsight-former-ph-d-students-reflect-on-why-they-jumped-ship)). Intellectual curiosity and interest in what you are going to spend a couple years of your life is important. For funded PhD students ([don't get a PhD without funding](https://www.insidehighered.com/blogs/gradhacker/unfunded-phds-go-or-not-go)), getting into a program means someone is going to pay you to do a very deep dive and learn something that wasn't know before. Factor in the fact that the odds are very low that you can do this once you enter industry or government and for those with the intellectual curiosity and interest it doesn't take much to at least apply for the PhD.

Finally, a note on financial compensation. In the [United States the average salary](https://www.higheredjobs.com/salary/salaryDisplay.cfm?SurveyID=24) of a new assistant professor (tenure track) is $65,372. The starting pay for STEM is [highly dependent upon your field](http://time.com/money/4189471/stem-graduates-highest-starting-salaries/) but the range seems to be $55,087 to $64,891 for a Bachelors and $72,080 to $73,871 for a Masters. So on the face of it the professor isn't as highly paid; however, that's just raw compensation for 9 months work. [Soft money](https://www.insidehighered.com/advice/2012/04/02/essay-building-career-soft-money-position) or consulting can result in higher pay during the summer and the costs associated with attending conferences usually isn't factored into the compensation as well. So doing a direct *net compensation* comparison can be quite difficult. Also, putting a financial value on surviving the PhD and spending the time pursing intellectual curiosity and interest may be impossible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fact-based and very referenced answer. I can imagine that a good amount of time must have been spent on it.

Answer (score 28):

You are asking why people might choose a doctoral candidacy over a **better-paying** job in the industry.
The straightforward answer is that - at least to the respective people - other factors are given more weight than achieving a maximum in payment alone.
These other factors can include:

- freedom in choice of tasks
- flexibility in working style
- ownership of what you work on
- autonomy in collaboration with internal and external partners
- authority to draw further people in to your tasks
- your colleagues are probably there because they're enthusiastic about what they're doing, not just because they want some job with an acceptable salary
- your organisation probably covers a wide range of topics, and any acquisition of knowledge within (or sometimes even outsode of) your organisation can be reasonably counted as working time

Evidently, various of these aspects depend a bit on the concrete situation a doctoraĺ candidacy takes place in.

Lastly, even a payment angle *can* play into it: I consider it a *significant* advantage that during the time of my doctoral candidacy (this being a government-funded job), I used to be paid based upon a salary table with automatic raises rather than having to negotiate for any amount of money.

Comment: The last two points "autonomy in collaboration" and "authorty to draw further people" are not specific to PhDs. The same policy applies to certain industrial positions: if you have luck with it and are allowed to do that by your contract, feel free.

Comment: @LeonMeier Perhaps, but if people choose to do a PhD, there is the consideration that this _will_ lead to a job with autonomy in collaboration (if it leads to a job in academia at all), while looking for a job in industry _might_ lead to a job with autonomy in collaboration.

Comment: @LeonMeier: That applies to almost all of the points, but it rather requires rising to a certain position in industry first.

Comment: @sgf My experience that a PhD is autonomous, but nobody from the industry will speak to you unless you can really offer them something they need - which has a high chance of forcing you into an NDA. Yes, and you have an authority of drawing people into your task, but why should anyone care about your task?

Comment: It is seldom the case that "colleagues are ... enthusiastic about what they're doing". My experience is that they are saying "unless you do my stuff, we won't work together". It is the case that "your organisation probably covers a wide range of topics" only for large departments with over 20 chairs, but in general this is way too seldom.

Comment: As a good colleague once said, your salary is pain and suffering money. So, the more a job pays the more suffering you'll have to endure ;) (Assuming otherwise same level).

Comment: @LeonMeier: "nobody from the industry will speak to you unless you can really offer them something they need" - of course you have to have something of interest to them. The point is that you're allowed to contact them on your own in the first place. "which has a high chance of forcing you into an NDA" - not every external body you contact will require you to sign an NDA, and in any case, it's still *your* choice whether you agree with what *they* offer. "why should anyone care about your task?" - because they (BSc/MSc students) are looking for a project/thesis topic that you can offer, ...

Comment: ... or (if your own funding or department has the appropriate resources) a student RA position. Or because they (other researchers) are just as eager as you to find opportunities to expand their research into new (maybe even interdisciplinary!) directions and collaborate on a paper - why in the world wouldn't they? "colleagues are [seldom] enthusiastic (...) unless you do my stuff, we won't work together" - it is unfortunate if an institution allows such a poisonous atmosphere to develop. I still tend to hope it is rather an exception. ...

Comment: ... "only for large departments with over 20 chairs" - at least in my place, universities usually span more than a few fields, thereby creating diverse mixtures ranging from CS over biology to politics. All of this, of course, may well vary by location and by field; my answer was primarily based upon my own experiences and those of other people in academia I got in touch with.

Answer (score 11):

*Too long for a comment.* Replying to various other answer which (I believe) are misleading, and sometimes just incorrect.

Various of the answers seem to be rather negative, and unfortunately I think this is the wide perception -- however, that doesn't mean it is true. To the answer saying "students don't know what to do so stay at university", I would reply this. While that may be true for *some* people, in my department I haven't come across a single person who gives this impression. The same holds regarding peer pressure.

For me personally, and for the people I know, we're doing a PhD because we love our subject. I really enjoy doing maths research: I find it incredibly interesting! Moreover, I love that I can contribute to open-source knowledge, not have my work kept hidden by an employer. I do pure maths, although vaguely applicable (eg to computer science) -- it's not that it's applied maths which would be directly used, but I'm developing techniques, etc.

While this isn't a reason for everyone, it certainly is the case for a lot of us. In fact, I **did** have a job offer, that I was genuinely interested in, and would've paid twice as much as I'm getting in my PhD (~£28/29k instead of ~£14k). However, I turned it down in favour of a PhD. Some of us just really enjoy research and contributing to society! :)

Comment: Agreed. PhD is not for anyone and certainly _not_ for people that _they do not know what to do_. You need to like the particulars of a PhD in order to pursue it.

Comment: Well, I can say I know many PhD students who still don't know what they want to do.  And I know many undergrads who've applied to grad school not sure what the want to do (though possibly more for master's applications).  Maybe this is a more common thing to do in the US, where the system is rather different.  (I guess you are in the UK.)

Comment: That's why I did... love of the subject, to become a monk!  The OP clearly believes that everyone goes to college to get a job.  But, as I later found out, my Ph. D. did get me a some jobs.

Comment: @Kimball -- yes, I certainly agree. I didn't know exactly what I wanted to do for a career when I started my PhD (and still don't), and I know a lot of PhD students don't know what they want to do. However, signing up for 4 years of (often pretty lonely) research if you're not fully is certainly not a good idea! It's poorly paid and hard work. I could've just taken a job not being sure it's what I wanted to do (I had a job offer for twice the money I'm getting currently, and I'd be working less than I do at my PhD), seen how it went, then maybe changed 2yrs in. I'd have been paid [cont...]

Comment: [... cont] much better than I am now, would've got experience in a work environment, which is well-known to be desired by employers. People who do PhDs aren't stupid: they know they could've gone for a job instead. Not being 100% sure of what you want to do doesn't mean that if you do a PhD then you're doing so because you don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 6):

Most PhD students are fresh graduates from university and thus have no working experience. They don't know what to do in their life, so they choose to stay in university.

Comment: Honestly, I have seen this quite a few times.

Comment: -1 Citation needed.

Comment: @anonymous Common knowledge...

Comment: @SmallChess Should be easy to find citations then. ;)

Comment: -1 Lots of "common knowledge" is absolute rubbish (eg bulls being aggravated by red or fish having a very short memory). What you've said does happen, but it's very infrequent -- 3yrs of research is a long time! This answer gives the "common knowledge" among bitter people: some people like to bring down others (often subconsciously): by doing this to people who have worked hard for their PhD, they feel it puts everyone on the same level. (Of course, someone with a PhD *isn't* inherently a better person -- but we have a culture of fear of others being better.)

Comment: Upvoted. Because even though this is not the only reason, this reason is a significant contributor. This reason can be generalized to 'a fear of industry's practices is an important contributor for people pursuing PhD, thereby causing competition'.

Comment: Define "most" please.

Comment: I agree that sometimes not knowing what you want to do can influence you to do a PhD, the thought process being "I'll gain further qualifications while I decide". However, I think this is *fairly* minor. After all, a PhD is often around 4yrs, and it's pretty lonely, so if you're not fully into it, you'll almost surely end up hating it. That said, I don't believe this is *at all* what the answerer is getting at (but, of course, I could be wrong!). (S)he appears to being saying "they don't know what to do, so just stay in university to put off deciding / having to get a real job".

Comment: -1 you don't just do a PhD because you don't know what you want to work on (in industry), because you need to know what you want to work on in order to do a PhD! This logic is completely backward, it's a wonder so many people upvoted this answer at all.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice  people upvote because I am right and you are wrong.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, a large percentage of PhD applicants at the US universities are foreigners who may have completely different reasons to apply than the domestic applicants. Often it's the only way to enter the US and get a job legally. Also, they may be expected to come back to their country and hold a high position within government. For a domestic applicant, a PhD from a reputable school opens new opportunities for work in industry and government.  It's becoming almost a requirement for certain positions. For instance, in Financial industry having a PhD in Math or related field can be more desirable than an MBA.  The reason for this is the fact that today American high tech workers have to compete for their jobs with workers from all over the world. Having not the best in the world STEM high school and college education makes them less competitive. HR departments are aware of this. Having a PhD from a reputable university is an attestation of a quality education and a person's ability to conduct research and close the deal (defend the thesis). On a lighter note, it also shows that the person is willing to work long hours for little praise.

Answer (score 1):

You are perfectly right. PhDs are underpaid and most of them don't get a tenure after graduating. Moreover, the "Dr." title doesn't count as much today as it was the case in the past. Speaking freely about your research is a value, but not if only 10 people on earth would understand you. You may not own your work (the government of the country may), but even if you do own your work, you most often cannot generate profit from it. Working style is "flexible": you may distribute your 16*7 out of 24*7 a week hours flexibly.

Earlier, PhD had an ideal touch. (Probably, that's the reason for so high application numbers.) Today, it's no more the case. Most of PhDs in STEM are simply doing engineering of various kinds, which they call applied science to maintain that touch and get more funding from the government. And the ones who do pure science undertake really heroic efforts or are geniuses. In addition, the PhDs do teaching and projects with the industry to get third-party money to finance themselves.

In short, nowadays, there is **no sense in pursuing a PhD** unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: All that you have mentioned, I have been reading in various sites, journals and magazines. It is sad.

Comment: That answer seems very field specific and very regional specific. I accept that this is what you have observed, but it does not generalize to my experiences and observations. Maybe you can add your field and country?

Comment: @MaartenBuis in STEM.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Would you mind sharing your experience?

Comment: It corresponds to a large extend with ORMapper

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson The answer is probably "ideal touch". Answer adapted.

Comment: @MaartenBuis OP specified STEM already

Comment: I don't understand what "ideal touch" means. Can you expand on that?

Comment: @FaheemMitha "An ideal touch" is not a well-defined, mathematical term. A feeling of idealism comes from being good enough to be paid for dealing with research problems, which means *generating and systematizing knowledge* as opposed to *solving the real-world problems*. These tasks may be related (and we wish to pay more if they are), but, by definition, they are different.