# What was the original purpose of a Ph.D.?

Tags: phd

When Ph.D. was first inducted into the universities, what was its actual purpose?

1. increasing employability
2. becoming eligible for working as a researcher
3. becoming eligible for obtaining a tenured professorship
4. vanity and prestige
   ...

??

Is the purpose the same or different nowadays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are merits of having a PhD degree?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93559/what-are-merits-of-having-a-phd-degree)

Comment: I suggest you read the *History* section of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy). That should answer your question. If it doesn't you need to ask a more focussed question (regarding country and time period) at the history stack.

Comment: Probably it depends on where in the world you are talking. Certainly in the places that originated the concept of the Doctorate, at the time when it originated, the sorts of people who go Doctorates were not the sorts of people who would ever have been employees; Research was a past time carried out by the rich, or patronized by rich, the state or the church in the same way art is; and there was no such thing as tenure.

Comment: Going back to the beginning it appears to have been viewed as a calling, something one did because one felt called to higher scholarship by temperament. Probably other factors too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically and culturally, the main role of a university is the advancement and transmission of knowledge. Universities award degrees to students as a recognition that they have achieved a particular level of knowledge in a particular domain. So from a very big picture point of view, employability inside or outside academia is just a consequence: people are qualified for jobs *because* they have the required knowledge, as confirmed by their degrees. Of course universities and students exist in the real world so the mundane necessities of life make employability a significant part of the question, but in principle at least it's not the main purpose of academia.

Vanity and prestige might also be a part of it, but that's true of any kind of achievement. In theory a PhD is just a diploma which confirms that the incumbent has the required knowledge and skills to do research in their domain. Historically this qualification led mostly to academic research, but it's clear that nowadays there's also a demand for PhD-level skills outside academia.

Answer (score -1):

In general, a PhD degree is the means by which you prove that you are capable of conducting research in an independent manner, without being told what to do by a professor. In other words, by obtaining a PhD degree, you prove that you are capable of contributing a completely new piece of knowledge to the currently existing body of scientific knowledge. You also prove that you are capable of defending your scientific hypothesis against external attacks by the reviewers.

Therefore, for a long time a PhD degree was primarily intended to help you become a researcher, or a faculty member in some higher educational institution. Students who entered a PhD course were expected to join the ranks of academia, or prestigious research labs.

As you can imagine, things have changed a lot. Universities smelled the sweet scent of money, and dramatically increased the number of PhD candidates beyond anything that was remotely reasonable; as a result, now, you have PhD degree holders working at Starbucks or at restaurants, trying to pay off their massive debt.

Therefore, there is now a push to redirect most PhD candidates into non-academic careers, instead of joining the dwindling, bitterly competitive ranks of academia.